# Google App Engine won't deploy when using <%@ include file="/file.jsp" %>

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, jstl

The project compiles and runs perfectly on my local computer. Whenever I try to deploy I get this error:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the      generated JSP java files.
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:803)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:760)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:592)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:370)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1163)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:232)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:109)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:105)
```

I googled a lot and applied every possible solution I found. I made sure Eclipse is using the JDK and not JRE. I even tried puting the tools.jar from the jdk into the lib/shared of AppEngineSDK. Nothing worked, so I decided to try another approach - I used the Guestbook demo as a start point. The Guestbook demo deployed perfectly when unmodified. But then I modified it. I move the code below from guestbook.jsp in separate .jsp file (includement.jsp). And then I use <%@ include file="/includement.jsp" %> in guestbook.jsp. And this is it. It works perfectly on my local computer. But it won't deploy giving me the error shown above.

Here is the code I moved:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<%
String guestbookName = request.getParameter("guestbookName");
if (guestbookName == null) {
    guestbookName = "default";
}
pageContext.setAttribute("guestbookName", guestbookName);
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
  pageContext.setAttribute("user", user);
%>
```

I have been struggling for a week now and I am pretty much desperate. It just doesn't make any sense to me that it works locally and won't get deployed.

Comment: Have you tried using <jsp:include page="includement.jsp"> instead?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem. I am having the same issues as you have pointed.

Comment: Me too facing the same issue. Please let us know if anyone found a solution for this issue.

Comment: I don't see "include" anywhere in the JSP sample you provided

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... this doesn't answer your question, but maybe it'll help others.

I just had a very similar situation. Worked fine locally but when deploying I got a file not found error. I went to this page (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles) on static files, and it got me thinking.

My include files didn't have a jsp extension and were considered to be static files by the app engine, therefore they could be served from any server. The opposite meaning to that is jsp files are served from only one server, and since the include files were referenced from a jsp page they have the same constraints -- they cannot be static files. When you think of it, it makes sense. The include files when served locally will act in sequence and no issues with page creation. Put those same files on other servers and you have synching issues. It makes a lot more sense to keep the include files local to the page being served.

In my case I renamed my includes to jsp extensions and it worked great. Not so in your case since you have a jsp extension already -- which is odd.

--edit--

Spoke too soon. It worked and broke again. Now gae returns "Failed to compile the generated JSP java files". Works fine locally of course...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I did following changes in included page and it worked!

- Imported and included all classes and libs.
- Variables which were declared in containing page, passed them to included page via page context.

It may not be perfect solution but a workaround till GAE team comes back with correct solution.

Code Snippet

**[index.jsp]** which includes add_member.jsp and update_member.jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions" %>

// some more application specific code here
<%
long memberId = -1;
if(request.getParameter("MEMBER_ID")!=null) {
  memberId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("MEMBER_ID"));
  System.out.println("memberId: "+memberId);
}
// Look at all of our members
  for (Member member : members) {
    pageContext.setAttribute("member_name", member.firstName + " " +     member.lastName);
    if(memberId == member.id) {
      currentMember = member;
      pageContext.setAttribute("current_member",currentMember);
    }
    System.out.println("member.id: "+member.id);


 %>
     <li> <a href="/index.jsp?MEMBER_ID=<%=member.id%>"> 

${fn:escapeXml(member_name)} </a></li>
  <%
      }
    %>
  </ul>
    <%
    }
  %>

</div>
<%
System.out.println("currentMember: "+currentMember);
  if(currentMember == null) {
%>

  <%@ include file="/pages/add_member.jsp" %>

<%
  } else {
    %>

    <%@ include file="/pages/update_member.jsp" %>

    <%
  }
%>
```

**[add_member.jsp]**
 Here, I have again imported the necessary libs and packages to make it run in GAE. This won't be necessary if you are running in local server.

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<div id="main">
  <%
    String picBlobKey = request.getParameter("blob-key");
    System.out.println("picBlobKey: "+picBlobKey);
```

**[update_member.jsp]**
 Same changes as is in add_member.jsp. Another change to notice is reading of page context attribute "current_member" which is set in index.jsp. By this way, able to share the variables used in parent page.

```
 <%@ page import="com.rotary.server.entities.Member" %>

<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<div id="main">
  <%
    Member current_member = (Member)pageContext.getAttribute("current_member");
```

Comment: Where exactly are you in contact with the "GAE team"? Do you just mean that someone should come and comment on this thread?

Comment: Also, this would be a much more helpful (valid?) answer if it demonstrated what you mean by your bullet points by showing the relevant JSP file contents, etc.

Comment: @Nick, Since this question is related and tagged with GAE, I was expecting somebody from GAE would respond. Edited my answer with code snippets.

Comment: To run locally -> mvn appengine:devserver

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that JSPs included in another JSP are able to be compiled without importing their own proper dependencies. I've been unable to find examples of this anywhere. It's odd that you say this worked in the dev server.

Here's two example JSPs, a main page and one which is included:

**index.jsp**

```
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<head>
</head>                                                                                                                                                                                           
<body>                                                                                         
    <pre>                                                                                                  
        <%@ page import="java.util.List" %> 
        <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>                                                                   
        <jsp:include page="include.jsp" />                                                                                           
    </pre>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
</html>
```

**include.jsp**

```
<%
List<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();                                                                        
cats.add ("Milo");                                                                                             
cats.add ("Dya");                                                                        
for (Object cat : cats) {                                                                                      
   out.println (cat.toString());                                                                               
}                                                                                                           
%>
```

This fails by displaying the following in the browser:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /include.jsp
List cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%
2: 
3: 
4: List<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();
5: cats.add ("Milo");
6: cats.add ("Dya");
7: 


An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /include.jsp
ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%
2: 
3: 
4: List<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();
5: cats.add ("Milo");
6: cats.add ("Dya");
7:
```

---

This is resolved when properly page-importing the classes within the JSP which uses them:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>                                                                    
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>                                                                                                                
<%                                                                                                            
List<String> cats = new ArrayList<String>();                                                                   
cats.add ("Milo");                                                                                             
cats.add ("Dya");                                                                                            
for (Object cat : cats) {                                                                                      
   out.println (cat.toString());                                                                               
}                                                                                                             
%>
```

This produces the nice output of the names of two wonderful little cats, as expected:

```
Milo
Dya
```